Pyspark Regular Expression add double quotes after comma
I have below string present within dataframe:
30,kUsUO,6,18,97,42,SAM,lmhYK,49,aLaTA,51,34,3,49,75,39,pdwvW,54,7,63,12,25,26,SJ12u,rUFUV,34,xXBv3,XHtz4,r4Fyh,14,20,0jZL2,izrsC,44,K5Kw3,8,tcKu7,5,RPLcy,kg4IR,Kvs3p,lyG09,dJmZB,34,84,7,qED2y,8uNen,5,96,81,88,bGgqK,FAsIV,81,YXZ,PQR,Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh,22,591213,LbAo7,21,18,text,,,,,
Requirement here to add  double quote after 57th comma if string/digits immidiately present after 57th comma and close double quote  before pattern digits,digits (here before ,22,591213)
So basically trying to enclose below substring within double quote
"Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh"
For that I have written below regular expression
Pattern=r"^((?:[^,]*,){57})(\"?[a-zA-Z_][^\"]*?\"?)(,\d{2},\d{4}.*)$"

df = df.withColumn("text", regexp_replace(col("text"), pattern, r'$1"$2"$3'))

This regular expression works very well for above string.
But If i get variation in string , example below then count for comma goes wrong
30,kUsUO,6,18,97,42,"SAM,K,KARAN" lmhYK,49,aLaTA,51,34,3,49,75,39,pdwvW,54,7,63,12,25,26,SJ12u,rUFUV,34,xXBv3,XHtz4,r4Fyh,14,20,0jZL2,izrsC,44,K5Kw3,8,tcKu7,5,RPLcy,kg4IR,Kvs3p,lyG09,dJmZB,34,84,7,qED2y,8uNen,5,96,81,88,bGgqK,FAsIV,81,YXZ,PQR,Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh,22,591213,LbAo7,21,18,text,,,,,
Here name appears within double quote with comma "SAM,K,KARAN" Due to this my count for comma goes wrong
Is there any way to modify above regular expression in pyspark so that expression will not consider comma if its present within double quote.
This double quote comma case appears any number of times and places.

Perhaps like this? ^((?:[^,\n"]*(?:"[^\n"]*"[^,\n"]*)*,){57})("?[a-zA-Z_][^"\n]*?"?)(,\d{2},\d{4}.*)$  See https://regex101.com/r/VXPDq9/1

You might change the regex to:
^((?:[^,"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^,"]*)*,){57})("?[a-zA-Z_][^"]*"?)(,\d{2},\d{4}.*)$

The different groups match:

^ Start of string
( Capture group 1
(?: Non capture group to repeat as a whole

[^,"]* Match optional chars other than "
(?:"[^"]*"[^,"]*)*, Optionally repeat matching "..." followed by optional chars other than , and then match a ,


){57} Close the non capture group and repeat 57 times
) Close group 1
( Capture group 2

"? Match an optional "
[a-zA-Z_] Match a single char specified in the character class
[^"]*"? Match optional chars other than " and then match an optional "


) Close group 2
( Capture group 3

,\d{2},\d{4}.* Match a comma, 2 digits, comma, 4 digits and then the rest of the line


) Close group 3
$ End of string

See a regex demo

Thank you for this , Appreciate your help!!!
Is there need of \n within [^,\n"],  ??
There is no new line, it just  caused due to formatting issue.
All string present within same line.

@GouravJoshi Ah I see, no you can omit that if you only have single lines. I added it in the example regex demo as there are 2 lines for demonstration.

one help needed , Currently given regx tried to find digit followed by digit pattern  \d{2},\d{4} which is correct but it should add double quote before first occurrences of  \d{2},\d{4} .Currently its adding double quote before last occurrence  \d{2},\d{4}
example  43,34531,,,,,,,, 44,591316
its considering 44,591316 as pattern and added double quote before it , it should add before first occurrences digits(2), digits(4) which is  43,34531

@GouravJoshi You could make the quantifier for the character class [^"\n]*?  non greedy, see https://regex101.com/r/vRYaBB/1

Thank you very much !!!

Thank you very much !!! One small suggestion needed . Sometimes below filed start with number instead of character (a-z) like below ,
1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh   //case1
02 Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh     //case2
59234 Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh  //case3
flat no 102, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh //case4
for this case i have tried to change Regx like below but no luck
^((?:[^,\n"](?:"[^\n"]"[^,\n"]),){57})("?[0-9][a-zA-Z_][^"\n]?"?)(,\d{2},\d{4}.)$

@GouravJoshi Let me check, 1 moment...

@GouravJoshi Can you add the lines for you that do not match to this regex demo, and then save it and paste the new link back in the chat? https://regex101.com/r/cT1WCe/1

https://regex101.com/r/F9Agky/1
Case -01 102 Flat No B1002, Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh
Case-02 102/34 Flat No B1002,Balaji Whitefield society, sus road, pune,Mh

@GouravJoshi LIke this? https://regex101.com/r/kncnRN/1

Yes Looks correct !!! awesome , Many Many Thanks !!!!!!

Firstly, your second example appears to have an error. You show "SAM,K,KARAN" lmhYK, whereas the first example has the lmhYK as a separate field, commas on both side (,lmhYK,). So I figured the space in front of the lmhYK was supposed to be a comma. My solution is made according to my corrected assumption. Essentially it can accept any/all of the fields in a record as having "" surrounding them. The field starts with a " and finishes with a ", and there are no nested "" within the field. So it counts 57 fields and then it records characters such that it should stop when immediately in front is a comma, some digits and another comma. I hope that this is sufficient to prevent it over running into the next field.
([^",]+,|("[^"]+"),){57}(.+?(?=,\d+,))

